# Can't access linux / GRUB menu (dual-boot)

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, grub

I have just installed linux mint on my Windows 10 laptop. Linux was working fine. After installation completes it recommends you restart, which I did.

I thought (based on the videos I watched) the GRUB menu would show at boot that would enable me to select the OS, however it boots straight into windows (I have tried pressing F8, F10 and holding shift with no luck).

I have also tried installing EasyBCD, but I'm unable to add an entry because it detects EFI given that the laptop is UEFI (not fully understanding this part).

Is there any other way I can get a boot menu to display when I turn my laptop on?

Answer (score 0):

launch a livecd linux and get boot-repair. Launch it and click on the "recommended" button and that should fix it!

If not you should disable secure boot in BIOS

how to access BIOS: go into windows and restart by holding shift while you press restart button. then you should find the option restart in BIOS then find the option disable secure boot. if it doesnt work for you then there should be also an option legacy boot enable that.